Horror short story from the 1970s - Rock Band Vampires / Demons
I'm trying to trace a fantasy / horror short story from the 1970s about a rock band who were actually vampires / demons. I'd really appreciate some pointers, if anyone else remembers it too.
It might be from a Pan Horror collection or similar? The story is about a rock band who are never seen without their make-up and everyone thinks this is their signature thing. At the time I read it, their make-up seemed to be reminiscent of the band Kiss, all black and white and scary. Anyway, this groupie / fan just won't leave them alone and in the end, she is finally invited backstage. She is then eaten.
Might not sound like much, but it's really well-written,  build up plot and tension brilliantly and has stuck with me for over 50 years! Would love to read it again.

That vaguely rings a bell. Was the band destroyed by the protagonist by setting the venue on fire?

Ah, it was Jennifer's Body (2009) I was thinking of.

Thank you for taking the time to answer me, but this story is definitely from the 1970s. Will look up the one you've mentioned though!

yeah, that's why I kept it as a comment once I realised this was much later.

@SQB That's a scene from Interview With the Vampire, but it's set in ninteenth-century Paris, not the present day.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.
